# cannot connect to raspberry pi 4 from javascript

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, networking, raspberry-pi4

I am facing an issue while sending a fetch request from a nodeJS scripture react-native app or reactJs side.

I am not the same network I connected to the hotspot of Raspberry Pi 4  when I run this script of python it is working fine.

```
import requests

# TODO: Change the URL to your Jetson Nano IP address
url = "https://10.42.0.1:5000/wifi"
cert_path = "/Users/artemiikhristich/Desktop/TextureExtraction3/Network/certs/certificate.crt"  # Update with your actual certificate path
data = {"ssid": "Blueground", "password": "Showupstartliving1"}

try:
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("WiFi credentials sent successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Error sending WiFi credentials. Status code: {response.status_code}")
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

**But if I run this script of Axois or Fetch it has Network Error.**

```
const test_iCast_wifi = () => {
    setMyTestLoading(true);
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      ssid: 'HUAWEI_B818_4211',
      password: '4RM9LE059DG',
    });

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
    };

    fetch('https://10.42.0.1:5000/wifi', requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setMyTestLoading(false);
        Alert.alert('test_iCast_wifi SUCCESS', JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error, "ERROR");
        setMyTestLoading(false);
        Alert.alert('test_iCast_wifi ERROR', JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };
```